# Error of creating Rcpp NumericVector with more than 20 elements

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I created a vector with 75 elements in Rcpp, using:

```
NumericVector c = NumericVector::create(-0.4297, 0.8616, ... , 25.7154);
```

Then came to the error: no matching function for call to 'create'.

Nothing is wrong when I use same code to create a vector with less than 20 elements.

I know I could use

```
NumericVector c(75);
x[0] = -0.4297;
x[1] = 0.8616;
...
x[74] = 25.7154;
```

But the code will be too long...I wonder if there are any other way to solve this.

I know there is a same question before [How create an Rcpp NumericVector with more than 20 entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541104/how-create-an-rcpp-numericvector-with-more-than-20-entries), but I cannot use any loop since there are no relation among elements.

Comment: That's Q that has been asked and answered before.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I don't think [How create an Rcpp NumericVector with more than 20 entrie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541104/how-create-an-rcpp-numericvector-with-more-than-20-entries) solves my problem. The elements in my case are independent and I cannot use loop to create it.

Comment: Of course it is. The set of `...::create()` constructors are _explicitly_ created by a set of MACROS.  How big a vector can be has no limit (beyond ram).  Just construct is differently, maybe via C array, or in more modern ways via C++11 initializer and then pass that down to Rcpp.

Comment: And, I should add, those MACROS stop at around 24 args or so. Which is plenty.  When you need more, either create a custom constructor, or do as the other answer here suggested and use a different constructor.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I use another way to construct it. Thank you!!!